# jdbcTemplate.queryForList returns list of Map where all column values are NULL

Tags: jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc

Any calls using jdbcTemplate.queryForList returns a list of Maps which have NULL values for all columns. The columns should've had string values.

I do get the correct number of rows when compared to the result I get when I run the same query in a native SQL client.

I am using the JDBC ODBC bridge and the database is MS SQL server 2008.

I have the following code in my DAO:

```
public List internalCodeDescriptions(String listID) {
  List rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select CODE, DESCRIPTION from CODE_DESCRIPTIONS where LIST_ID=? order by sort_order asc", new Object[] {listID});
  //debugcode start
  try {
    Connection conn1 = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    Statement stat = conn1.createStatement();
    boolean sok = stat.execute("select code, description from code_descriptions where list_id='TRIGGER' order by sort_order asc");
    if(sok) {
        ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        String columnname1=rsmd.getColumnName(1); 
        String columnname2=rsmd.getColumnName(2);
        int type1 = rsmd.getColumnType(1);
        int type2 = rsmd.getColumnType(2);
        String tn1 = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1);
        String tn2 = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(2);

        log.debug("Testquery gave resultset with:");
        log.debug("Column 1 -name:" + columnname1 + " -typeID:"+type1 + " -typeName:"+tn1);
        log.debug("Column 2 -name:" + columnname2 + " -typeID:"+type2 + " -typeName:"+tn2);

        int i=1;
        while(rs.next()) {
            String cd=rs.getString(1);
            String desc=rs.getString(2);
            log.debug("Row #"+i+": CODE='"+cd+"' DESCRIPTION='"+desc+"'");
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        log.debug("Query execution returned false");
    }
    } catch(SQLException se) {
        log.debug("Something went haywire in the debug code:" + se.toString());
    }


    log.debug("Original jdbcTemplate list result gave:");
    Iterator<Map<String, Object>> it1= rows.iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext()) {
        Map mm = (Map)it1.next();
        log.debug("Map:"+mm);
        String code=(String)mm.get("CODE");
        String desc=(String)mm.get("description");
        log.debug("CODE:"+code+" : "+desc);
    }
    //debugcode end
    return rows;
}
```

As you can see I've added some debugging code to list the results from the queryForList and I also obtain the connection from the jdbcTemplate object and uses that to sent the same query using the basic jdbc methods (listID='TRIGGER').

What is puzzling me is that the log outputs something like this:

```
Testquery gave resultset with:
Column 1 -name:code -typeID:-9 -typeName:nvarchar
Column 2 -name:decription -typeID:-9 -typeName:nvarchar
Row #1: CODE='C1' DESCRIPTION='BlodoverxF8rin eller bruk av blodprodukter'
Row #2: CODE='C2' DESCRIPTION='Kodetilfelle, hjertestans/respirasjonstans'
Row #3: CODE='C3' DESCRIPTION='Akutt dialyse'
...
Row #58: CODE='S14' DESCRIPTION='Forekomst av hvilken som helst komplikasjon'

...

Original jdbcTemplate list result gave:
Map:(CODE=null, DESCRIPTION=null)
CODE:null : null
Map:(CODE=null, DESCRIPTION=null)
CODE:null : null
...
```

58 repetitions total.

Why does the result from the queryForList method return NULL in all columns for every row? How can I get the result I want using jdbcTemplate.queryForList?

The xF8 should be the letter ø so I have some encoding issues, but I can't see how that may cause all values - also strings not containing any strange letters (se row#2) - to turn into NULL values in the list of maps returned from the jdbcTemplate.queryForList method.

The same code ran fine on another server against a MySQL Server 5.5 database using the jdbc driver for MySQL.

Comment: Why do you use the JDBC ODBC bridge? Could you try with a Microsoft or jTDS JDBC driver?

Comment: I dont' have the option to copy files to that server (it's on a secured network without access to the internet). I did convince the customer's system administrator to copy the MS SQL Server jdbc driver to the server and that did indeed fix the issue. I didn't hold much hope that it would since I got data using "plain" jdbc-code and not while using jdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using the MS SQL Server jdbc driver rather than using the JDBC ODBC bridge. I don't know why it didn't work with the bridge though.